# Convex non-increasing, but not lower semicontinuous function?

Tags: convex-analysis

I am trying to think of an example of a function $f:\unicode{x211D}^n \rightarrow \unicode{x211D}$ that is convex and non-increasing, but not lower semicontinuous, without any luck. Is this actually possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A convex function from ${\mathbb R}^n$ to $\mathbb R$ is always continuous, not just lower semicontinuous.  To get examples that are not lower semicontinuous you must allow values of $+\infty$.  For example, with $n=1$, $f(x) = +\infty$ for $x \le 0$, $0$ for $x > 0$.

Comment: So saying that a function is convex and lower semicontinuous is equivalent of saying that the function is convex and continuous. Is that right?

Comment: Careful. If there are no infinite values then convex & lsc implies continuous. Otherwise the above is a counterexample.

Comment: Can you tell something about the infinite-dimensional case?

Comment: A lower semicontinuous real-valued convex function on an open 
convex subset of a Banach space is continuous.